# What does it mean "Lager Malt" in this recipe (FreeBeer)

Tags: recipe, malt

I'm trying to brew FreeBeer 1.0 https://github.com/FreeBrewers/Vores
My question is: what is "Lager malt" they talking about?

I think this is just a malt type (for example for Pilsner malt) but after googling i find English Lager Malt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this malt you need to put it into perspective with other malts and the region it comes from; the UK.

Historically, lager malt is a malt made from popular English strains of barley that would be used to make English Pale or English Pale Ale malt (like Maris Otter, Golden Promise etc.)  English Ales classically made from 2 row base malt kilned to 3-5Lovibond in color are very malt forward.  Some English Maltsters would kiln 2-row to lower color ratings from the same barley strains. They would call this Lager malt.  My LHBS sells this stuff.

A reasonable substitute is actually, just American 2-row; not really Pilsner malt. Very different flavor than low kilned 2-row.

All that being said, you don't see this stuff in use very much professionally.

Comment: A 12% addition of a very simular base malt is nonsensical.

Comment: @EvilZymurgist I agree.  But most online recipes are garbage, to be honest.  I'm just saying what I know Lager malt to be.  That being said, I make a Munich Dunkel that only has 10-15% Pilsner malt in it.

Comment: [Muntons Lager Malt](http://www.muntonsmicrobrewing.com/products/lager-malt/)  Just for reference

Answer (score 1):

The Free Beer project has undergone many updates since its 1.0 version, like open source code. The 1st recipe was "buggy"; the most current version I've found is 4.1

http://freebeer.org/blog/

I can't find the intended malt they are calling Lager malt in 1.0 if I had to guess I would say **Melonoiden Malt**, since it's such a small addition I doubt it would be a "lager malt" like 2-row since pils is covered in base malts. Melonoiden would make this like a med-dark bock though an Ale.

The 12% of "Lager Malt" may suggest a reference to Carapills or Carafoam since these are brand names they gave it a generic label. Which is common in open source. These are common additions for added head retention and a little body but 12% is high. That's why I feel it is a speciality malt instead.

It may very well have been intended to be a generic place holder for "insert your own specialty malt"

All version are fermented at Ale temps though.